# How do I evaluate or add a watch to a variable in VS Code when stopped at a breakpoint in a framework using WebDriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using WebDriverIO to implement a test automation framework in TypeScript.  My framework includes some complex models for the application under test and I need to debug in VS Code to ensure that the models have been implemented correctly.

Unfortunately, although I have configured wdio.conf.js and .vscode/launch.json in such a manner as to properly start the debugging session and the execution stops at my breakpoint (most of the time?), I can't add a watch on any variables or properties of my model - nothing gets added in the watch window.  Similarly, if I use the debug console, nothing happens when I type in a property name.

I've tried using browser.debug() as per the documentation (https://webdriver.io/docs/debugging.html), but all that seems to be designed for is stopping your code execution so that you can evaluate the state of the application under test in the browser's DevTool console.

Doing console.log(this) in VS COde's debug console when the execution hits browser.debug() returns what looks like a WebDriverIO instance rather than the context of execution.

Has anyone had luck with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, include the word 'debugger' where you would like the debug execution to break. See example of 'debugger' placement.

```js
describe('Navigate and debug ', () => {
    it('should have the correct title', () => {
        browser.url('localhost')
        debugger
        assert.strictEqual(browser.getTitle(), 'foo')
    })
})
```